# How to add a custom item into the chrome context menu?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any API to be used to add a custom item into the chrome context menu?

For example:

Now, I wanna add a "*send to ...*" item to context menu(right click), when it is clicked the contents selected in the webpage will be sent to someone.

I searched the chrome APIS and found that [**chrome.experimental.contextMenu**](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.contextMenu.html) is competent for my requirement, however it is experimental API so something like "path_to_chrome.exe --enable-experimental-extension-apis" will be added.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 10):

Now (for long time) you have an option.

1. Add this permission to your manifest.json file

   ```
   "permissions": ["contextMenus"]
   ```
2. Then, something like that will do the trick:

   ```
   chrome.contextMenus.create({
     'title' : 'Open this select text %s',
     'contexts' : ['selection'],
     'onclick' : function(info, tab) {
        console.log('Selected link: ' + info.selectionText);
     }
   });
   ```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Using `contextMenu` is the one and only way (outside of hacking on the Chromium source), but the API should be graduating from `experimental` when Google Chrome 6 gets released to the stable channel.